# Developing a java based assembler for 8085

Tags: java

I am reading a text file which contains the assembly language program (like MOV A B; LDA 1600 etc). I want to convert this mnemonic code into object code (not in the same file but directly print them into the console).

For MOV I am replacing it by 01, A by 111, B by 000, C by 001, D by 010.
However  how should I replace MVI R,32 The opcode is 00rrr110 0011 0010 
Please suggest a general algorithm..

Comment: You can have a look into how the KAsm Z80 assembler written in Java does it.  Z80 is an extension onto the 8080 instruction set which the 8085 uses too. http://trimah.com/eng/index.php/tools-for-developers/1-kasm

Answer (score 1):

Start with replacing `rrr` with `000` in the opcode, resulting in `00000110=0x06`. Then take the value corresponding to your register from the lookup table (A=111, B=000, C=001, and so on), and shift it left by 3 positions using `<<` operator. Finally, `OR` the two values together, like this:

Declare this for use everywhere you need `rrr`: A is at index 0, B is at index 1, then there are C, D, E, H, and L

```
static int registerLookup[] = {0x07, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05}
```

For `MVI`, use this code:

```
int baseOpcode = 0x06; // MVI
int opcode = baseOpcode | registerLookup[regIndex]<<3;
```

Comment: It seems as if I got it.. However if I find any further problems, i will be posting here.. thnx  a lot for the help..

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say.. Bt i find it hard to implement in my algo... May be because of the fact that I am not using the instruction length in my program ... Plz help !!!!